# GPS in Application class or Service?

Tags: android, gps

If I need to implement GPS in my application which should be active only if the application is in the foreground - user do something in one activity, change this activity to another etc., but when the user turns off the app or minimizes it then I want it to turn off.

I wonder which method would be better. Implement GPS in Application class or Service?

Comment: You should implement it in Application class, I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know exactly where it is better, but wherever you put the location listener, you cannot exactly know when the Android system kills your application. To know when your application is in foreground/background you can implement an bind service, which is binded from onStart() method of every activity you have in application, and unbind in onStop(). If there are not activities binded, the service stops automatically, and then you remove the location updates listener. I hope this helps you.

Comment: It's helpful : ) But what about situation in which user switch between activities. onStop and then onStart will be called every time and service will be unbind and bind in every activities change.

Comment: Yup, you're right. I'll try it : ) So, i should implements service which onCreate gets system gps service and start service, then every activity onStart bind it and onStop unbind it? BTW. service works if there is atleast one bind, yeah?

Comment: Great! You are right: the service starts when you have at least one bind, and you should start GPS in service's onCreate().

Answer (score 3):

Implement it in the application class, and then override on the OnResume and OnPause methods to enable and disable the GPS listener

Comment: That's good idea i think. But about onResume and onPause. Is it not a problem fact that between activities change both are called everytime? I mean gps will stop and start between every activities change. I hope u know what i mean.

Comment: You could create a class that controls the gathering of GPS data, and then in the OnStart of every activity, have it add a reference to that activity to an array, and then add/remove it when OnResume and OnPause are called. Then it's just a matter of checking if a reference to an activity still exists.

Comment: Maybe it's a solution : ) Anyway i used Service to do this, it works perfect!